# IE´s createPopup() function when in an iframe on a different domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, internet-explorer-9

I have two web applications. One runs in an iframe of the other. They are on the same domain-suffix, but have different subdomains.
E.g. 
Main app is: www.localhost.com and inside of it, I have an iframe which has domain domain.localhost.com.

In the domain.localhost.com there is an old 3rd party javascript that runs var foo = window.createPopup();
Then, whenever foo.show(some args) is called, I get "SCRIPT5: access denied". This is of course only for IE9 (sigh)... some kind of security feature to avoid phishing attacks if I´ve understood correctly.

Is there any way of hacking my way around this, or do I need to rewrite parts of this 20k line big javascript?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

El Che